# How can you pass a url to an iframe via textInput() in r shiny?

Tags: r, iframe, shiny

I need to embed a webpage reached through a URL inputted by the user.
I found this script but I can't make the iframe depend on a textInput() containing a URL. This example fails and I am not sure why.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput('url','url',value = "www.google.com"),
  uiOutput('o')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$o = renderUI({
    tags$iframe(src=input$url)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Getting Iframe"), 
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    textInput("url", label = "Enter url"), 
                    actionButton("go", "Go")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(
                    htmlOutput("frame")
                  )
                ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$frame <- renderUI({
    validate(need(input$go, message=FALSE))
    tags$iframe(src=isolate(input$url), height=600, width=535)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I get a white iframe. I thought it was slow so i waited but nothing comes up. I get an error if i type "www.google.com". Instead get a white space with "https://www.google.com"

Comment: Other websites work but Google doesn't seem to allow this.